# Querying Adjacent Polygon Features using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, adjacency

I have a layer of polygon features representing forest stands with a vegetation type and age. For every forest stand I want to assign it a value in an empty field if any of the adjacent stands have a specific vegetation type and age.

How would I go about doing this inside ArcMap?

Comment: Edit your question to include how you define adjacency, a picture always helps.

Comment: [PolygonNeighbors](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/analysis-toolbox/how-polygonneighbors-analysis-works.htm) seems to be the tool of choice.